# I want to delete this field from the flutter application, what should I do?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the code that I want to delete the field from -

```dart
setPincode() {
  return TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: pincodeC,
    readOnly: true,
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .subtitle2
        .copyWith(color: colors.fontColor),
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    onSaved: (String value) {
      pincode = value;
    },
    validator: (val) =>
      validatePincode(val, getTranslated(context, 'PIN_REQUIRED')),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: getTranslated(context, 'PINCODEHINT_LBL'),
      isDense: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

Or you can see in this image what I want to remove
[image: What I want to remove]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function called `setPincode` that returns this TextFormField. Don't call `setPincode` if you no longer need it.